# Rails 4 Routing Error - no rout matches [POST] "/categories/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

While learning Rails 4 I stuck while trying to add categories to posts of my simple blog. I have generated model, ran the migration and added a controller. No matter what I do now when trying to create a category, I keep running into same mistake: no route matches [POST], which is weird, as I seem to have all the code in place. Please help!

categories controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @categories = Category.all
    end

    def new
      @category = Category.new
    end

    def create
      @category = Category.new(category_params)

        @category.save
        redirect_to new_category_path, alert: "Category created!"
    end

    def show
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
      @category.destroy

      redirect_to categories_path
    end


  private
        def category_params
            params.require(:category).permit(:name)
        end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag

  resources :categories

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :posts
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :category do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

/categories/new

```
No route matches [POST] "/categories/new"
```

Comment: Can you add whole backtrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have in your view

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

`@category` object is used by `form_for` method to figure out form url.

If you pass only `Symbol` to `form_for` method, without specifying `url` explicitly, form will be generated with url being the current url.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. In the begginer tutorial they are using :symbol within the form. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html Could you maybe kindly explain why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Although the `@category` works, if you read a bit further you will see that they will explain why the your code sends `No route matches [POST] "/categories/new"`.

The guide actually explains that you need to specify the `url: posts_path` for the form to use the right route.

> There's one problem with this form though. If you inspect the HTML
>   that is generated, by viewing the source of the page, you will see
>   that the action attribute for the form is pointing at /posts/new. This
>   is a problem because this route goes to the very page that you're on
>   right at the moment, and that route should only be used to display the
>   form for a new post.
>
> The form needs to use a different URL in order to go somewhere else.
>   This can be done quite simply with the :url option of form_for.
>   Typically in Rails, the action that is used for new form submissions
>   like this is called "create", and so the form should be pointed to
>   that action.
>
> Edit the form_for line inside app/views/posts/new.html.erb to look
>   like this:
>
> ```
> <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
> ```
>
> In this example, the
>   posts_path helper is passed to the :url option. What Rails will do
>   with this is that it will point the form to the create action of the
>   current controller, the PostsController, and will send a POST request
>   to that route.

Comment: thanks guys. I guess too much information overwhelms my brain capacities.